# ArrayList stuck on printing one item

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am making an app that displays messages pulled from Firebase and stored in an ArrayList. The app should display a single message for ten seconds, then scroll the message to show the next message.
I am using a textSwitcher view to display the message. My problem is that the app get stuck at the last message in the ArrayList and doesn't start again from the start of the array. 
Thank you in advance.

Here's the code for *position*:

```
public class ViewMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextSwitcher txtSwitcher;
    private ImageButton btnNext,btnPrev;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Messages");
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = ar.size();
    int position = 0;
    TextView hallName;
```

Here's the code responsible for this:

```
if(!ar.isEmpty()) {
    txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(0));
    count = ar.size();
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position++;
            if (position >= count)
                position = 0;
            txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(position));
        }
    });
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtSwitcher.showPrevious();
            --position;
            if (position < 0)
                position = ar.size() - 1;
            txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(position));
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried debugging? What values do you get for "position" in the critical moment of position == count? and on the next click when position should be 0

Comment: try position = (position + 1) % ar.size(); instead of the conditional if

Comment: When position == count, position == 1.
Should I try position = (position + 1) % ar.size(); instead if position = 0? I didn't work.

Comment: Here's a link showing a video of the problem. The database the (test1, test2, test3) messages. The app auto-scrolls _only_ **test1**. But clicking the left and right arrows show the other messages.

Here: [link](https://austae-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/201212006_aust_ae/EWJUx8jHIhFJswmD3n9REi4BLQLPI1mY6GLwfNZDgrUtXQ?e=YDwmGX)

Comment: I found the problem and fixed it. I was not updating the position in the ArrayList. Rookie mistake.
Instead of this code:
`if(!ar.isEmpty()) {
 txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(0));
 count = ar.size();`
I put this:

`if(!ar.isEmpty()) {
 txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(position));
 position++;
if (position >= count)
 position = 0;

count = ar.size();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it. I was not updating the position in the ArrayList. Rookie mistake.

Instead of this code:

```
if(!ar.isEmpty()) {
    txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(0));
    count = ar.size();
```

I put this:

```
if(!ar.isEmpty()) {
    txtSwitcher.setText(ar.get(position));
    position++;
if (position >= count)
    position = 0;

count = ar.size();
```